# ActiveRecord : find associated records with ALL conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to perform an activerecord query that essentially does the below.

I have 3 models in a many-to-many relationship

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_modifiers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :modifiers, through: :item_modifiers
end

class ItemModifier < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :modifier
end

class Modifier < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_modifiers
    has_many :items, through: :item_modifiers
end
```

Now I want to find all items that have modifiers with IDs 1 and 2

I have tried several things like:

```
Item.includes(:modifiers).where(modifiers: {id: 1}).where(modifiers: {id: 2})
```

This fails because it searches for modifiers where ID = 1 AND ID = 2 which is always false.

This also doesn't work

```
Item.includes(:modifiers).where(modifiers: {id: [1, 2]})
```

Because this does an IN (1, 2) query so it returns items with modifiers of either 1 or 2. I want items that have any modifiers as long as they have AT LEAST 1 modifier with ID 1 and AT LEAST 1 modifier with ID 2

I seem to be missing something quite simple but I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could like:

```
        Item.joins(:item_modifiers).where("item_modifiers.modifier_id=1 OR
 item_modifiers.modifier_id=2").group("items.id").having("COUNT(item_modifiers.id)=2")
```

If write in plain SQL, it could be:

```
  SELECT I.*, COUNT(IM.id) FROM items as I INNER JOIN item_modifiers AS IM on I.id=IM.item_id
 WHERE IM.modifier_id=1 OR IM.modifier_id=2 GROUP BY I.id HAVING COUNT(IM.id)=2
```

It will get all the items with its modifers' id include 1 and 2. Maybe in different DB, the statement need a slight change.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to take your idea and solve my specific problem using the below.

Item.include(:item_modifiers).where(item_modifiers: {modifier_id: params[:item_mods]}).group('items.id').having('COUNT(item_modifiers.id) >= ?', params[:item_mods].count)

Comment: I think you don't have to ">=", it is same as "=".